# Python 3 Tornado bytes and JSON issues

Tags: json, facebook, python-3.x, tornado

I stumbled into python 3, and specifically into tornado framework.

My task was to integrate facebook authentification, and i used test cases from here:

https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/master/demos/facebook

So the point is that `user` is a dictionary with bytes data.

```
class AuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        ....

    def _on_auth(self, user):
        if not user:
            raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Facebook auth failed")
        self.set_secure_cookie("fbdemo_user", tornado.escape.json_encode(user))
        self.redirect(self.get_argument("next", "/"))
```

_on_auth always produces this Error: `b'token or sesion_expire data here' is not JSON serializable`

Ive come out with few solitons found on stackoverflow:

`Fix` the data before encode

```
import collections.abc

def convert(data):
    '''
    Converts bytes data into unicode strings, so this can be encoded into JSON
    '''
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return str(data)
    elif isinstance(data, bytes):
        return data.decode('utf-8')
    elif isinstance(data, collections.abc.Mapping):
        return dict(map(convert, data.items()))
    elif isinstance(data, collections.abc.Iterable):
        return type(data)(map(convert, data))
    else:
        return data
# ... and somewhere in the code
tornado.escape.json_encode(convert(user))
```

And the next one is to extend the json itself:

```
import json

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, bytes):
            return o.decode('utf-8')
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

Now the question: why are there such an isses with data like `type(data) == <class 'bytes'>`, and am i doing it right?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is that `user` is not a dictionary, it is bytes string `b'token or sesion_expire data here'` which is indeed not JSON serializable. I recommend runnig your code in a debugger to find out where does it come from.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never.

Python 3 json encoder does not accept byte strings. Tornado provides a method `to_basestring` which can be used to overcome this problem.

Here's what the [source doc](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/tornado/escape.html#to_basestring) says about the issue:

> In python2, byte and unicode strings are mostly interchangeable, so
>   functions that deal with a user-supplied argument in combination with
>   ascii string constants can use either and should return the type the
>   user supplied. In python3, the two types are not interchangeable, so
>   this method is needed to convert byte strings to unicode.

Usage:

```
tornado.escape.to_basestring(value)
```

Comment: But still i must loop through each key and value that may contain byte string. There is no function that can deal with dict`s with bytes string into json? Extending JSONEncoder is the most neat solution that i still have.